# LogCosh Custom loss function returning nan

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, loss-function

I'm trying to implement the LogCosh function as a custom loss function. I get an error when I do this, as the fitting phase gets NaN as the loss. Even weirder, when I run it a bunch it starts to give actual values for the loss, then reaches a point where it starts returning NaN again.

My model:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(81,)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(300, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])
```

My loss function and data fitting:

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    x = y_true-y_pred
    return tf.math.log(tf.math.cosh(x))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=custom_loss,
              metrics=['MeanAbsoluteError'])

model.fit(train_features, train_labels, epochs=3)
```

This gives `NaN`:

```
Train on 21263 samples
Epoch 1/3
21263/21263 [==============================] - 1s 65us/sample - loss: nan - MeanAbsoluteError: nan
Epoch 2/3
21263/21263 [==============================] - 1s 51us/sample - loss: nan - MeanAbsoluteError: nan
Epoch 3/3
21263/21263 [==============================] - 1s 57us/sample - loss: nan - MeanAbsoluteError: nan
```

Why is it being garbage/how do I fix this issue so the loss actually works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to write any custom function for that. [`LogCosh`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/LogCosh) is already a built-in loss function available in `TF 2.4`.

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.LogCosh(),
              metrics=['MeanAbsoluteError'])
```

Comment: Thats not the point, I'm well aware of this fact... What part of "I'm trying to implement the LogCosh function as a custom loss function" was not clear? I'm using this built-in function as a reference to check if I'm doing custom loss functions right. If you know how to implement this as a custom function, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this :

```
tf.math.softplus(-2.0 * x) - tf.cast(tf.math.log(2.0), x.dtype)
```

Comment: please explain why this should work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).